# Combine Mono and Stereo Input with Superpowered Player

Tags: android, superpowered

I have 3 files, two are mono, one are stereo. I want to play them together. Currently my code is like this but seems the output is not correct.

```
bool silence = !player1->process(stereoBuffer, false, numberOfSamples, vol);
silence = !(playerLeft->process(stereoBuffer, !silence, numberOfSamples,vol));
silence = !(playerRight->process(stereoBuffer, !silence, numberOfSamples,vol));
if (!silence) {
        SuperpoweredFloatToShortInt(stereoBuffer, output, numberOfSamples);
        return true;
    }
```

Anyone know what is wrong here? I think i should use this method

```
void SuperpoweredFloatToShortIntInterleave(float *inputLeft, float *inputRight, short int *output, unsigned int numberOfSamples);
```

With 2 buffers for left and right, but then how can I add the data of the `player1` into those 2 buffers? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to logical OR the silence value with playerLeft and playerRight, because it can already be true after player1.

```
silence |= !playerLeft->process(...
silence |= !playerRight->process(...
```

You can also "flip" silence to "hasAudio" for an easier understanding:

```
bool hasAudio = player1->process(stereoBuffer, false, ...
hasAudio |= playerLeft->process(stereoBuffer, hasAudio, ...
hasAudio |= playerRight->process(stereoBuffer, hasAudio, ...
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, ya we can re-write like that. What I mean is, my 2 mono files convert into one stereo buffer. What I want is to output those 2 mono to the left and the right, not merged into one

Comment: You need to output each player into separate buffers. They will output interleaved stereo audio. For a mono source it means left and right in the buffers will be the same. Then use a function from SuperpoweredSimple.h to mix them into an output buffer.